# Using replace function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following in my page which is a textarea with some text in it:

[image]

and what i want to do now is to replace the BR in the text with newline \r such that i would get the following displayed in the textarea:

```
Hi
I
Am
Jake
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("sample").value);
document.getElementById("sample").value = document.getElementById("sample").value.replace("<BR>","\n");
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "outer">
        <textarea id="sample">Hi<BR>I<BR>Am<BR>Jake</textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be displaying properly. Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`. The replace function will replace only the first match, `replaceAll()` will replace all the occurrences in the given string.

I also suggest escaped strings in the replace parameters. Add backslash `(\)` in your `<` `>` characters.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("sample").value);
document.getElementById("sample").value = document.getElementById("sample").value.replaceAll("\<BR\>","\n");
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "outer">
        <textarea id="sample">Hi<BR>I<BR>Am<BR>Jake</textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CodeBug - So does your comment. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep LOL :-D

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's replace function only replaces the first instance. You can, however, use regex with the `/g` flag. I replaced `"<BR>"` with `/<BR>/g`, and it works (you just have to scroll). If you're interested, there is also [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), but that doesn't have that good browser support.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("sample").value);
document.getElementById("sample").value = document.getElementById("sample").value.replace(/<BR>/g,"\n");
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "outer">
        <textarea id="sample">Hi<BR>I<BR>Am<BR>Jake</textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value.split("<BR>").join("\n")` instead of `.value.replace("<BR>", "\n")`

```js
document.getElementById("sample").value = document.getElementById("sample").value.split("<BR>").join("\n");
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "outer">
        <textarea id="sample">Hi<BR>I<BR>Am<BR>Jake</textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
document.getElementById("sample").value = document.getElementById("sample").value.replace(/\<BR\>/g,"\n").trim();
```